# Make QGIS python plugin for both versions 2.x and 3.x?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt4, qgis-3, pyqt5

I am in the process of migrating a QGIS python plugin from `QGIS 2` to `QGIS 3`, and browsing various resources.

It's not clear if it's possible to have the plugin compatible with both versions or if it's necessary two handle to plugin versions.

The problem I hit so far is how to manage PyQt import (PyQt4/PyQt5) ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Documentation

Here you can find [what is new and what is break under the PyQGIS API](http://qgis.org/api/api_break.html).
To get details about how to port Python2 to Python3 [go there](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html)

You can find some detail about testing from QGIS2 to QGIS3 on this question :[Writing automated tests for QGIS plugins?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71206/writing-automated-tests-for-qgis-plugins?rq=1)

And you will find an interesting [OpenGis.ch's paper here](http://www.opengis.ch/2016/05/04/qgis-qt5-and-python3-migration-current-state/) about the migrations tools.

## What will change into my code

In fact, you need to change code of plugin that are not prepared to pass 
throught a new version.

You get [qgis.utils.QGis.QGIS_VERSION_INT](http://qgis.org/api/classQgis.html#a599a850991eeb103d08d7954439df9d4) function which is made to check the QGIS version. This is usefull when a function is deprecabled . For exemple `setSelectedFeatures` since 2.16.

By exemple with the use of `if` statement :

```
if qgis.utils.QGis.QGIS_VERSION_INT < 21600 :
            joinLayer.setSelectedFeatures( [ f.id() for f in request ] )
        else:
            joinLayer.selectByIds(  [ f.id() for f in request ] )
```

It's the same about `PyQt` object you import under your module. If you need compatibility, the price is to wrote more code line (the code with QGIS2 function and the code with QGIS3 functions AND also the code for checking the version and the capabilities to import new libraries ).

## About PyQt libraries

> The PyQt5 is not backward compatible with PyQt4; there are several
>   significant changes in PyQt5. However, it is not very difficult to
>   adjust older code to the new library. The differences are, among
>   others, the following:
>
> - Python modules have been reorganized. Some modules have been dropped
>     (QtScript), others have been split into submodules (QtGui, QtWebKit).
> - New modules have been introduced, including QtBluetooth, QtPositioning, or Enginio.
> - PyQt5 supports only the new-style signal and slots handlig. The calls to SIGNAL() or SLOT() are no longer supported. PyQt5 does not
>     support any parts of the Qt API that are marked as deprecated or
>     obsolete in Qt v5.0.

source : (http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/introduction/)

Here is some exemples of changes into your from/import statement:

Remember with PyQt4 you had to look on the API's doc:
for exemple
[PyQT4 QtCore module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtcore.html)
[PyQT4 QtGui module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtgui.html)

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication, Qt, QObject, SIGNAL

from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QDialog, QFormLayout
```

And with PyQt5 you have now to look on those API's doc :
[PyQt5 QtCore module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtCore.html#PyQt5-QtCore)
[PyQt5 QtGui module](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/QtGui.html#PyQt5-QtGui)

so that become :

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QVersionNumber, QCoreApplication, Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal 
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QDialog, QFormLayout
```

### Note that :

> QtGui module has been split into submodules. The QtGui module contains
>   classes for windowing system integration, event handling, 2D graphics,
>   basic imaging, fonts and text. It also containes a complete set of
>   OpenGL and OpenGL ES bindings (see [Support for
>   OpenGL](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/opengl.html#ref-opengl)).
>   Application developers would normally use this with higher level APIs
>   such as those contained in the QtWidgets module.

And  PyQt5 supports only the new-style signal and slots handlig! [have a look to this page](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/eventssignals/) to understand how to use `pyqtSignal`, `connect` and `e` event object instead of use `SIGNAL`.

### Make it compatible

So with compatibility between PyQt4/PyQt5 (and QGIS2 / QGIS3 as well)
you need to try/except the import before use the pyQt5 librarie.

```
try:
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, QVersionNumber, QCoreApplication, Qt, QObject, pyqtSignal 
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon 
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QDialog, QFormLayout

except:
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings, QTranslator, qVersion, QCoreApplication, Qt, QObject, SIGNAL
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QAction, QIcon, QDialog, QFormLayout
```

And don't forget that you need to change also some specific function under your code by adding try/except or if statement.

Comment: Great answer, something that will greatly help is to first replace any `from PyQt4.QtCore import *` with `from PyQt4.QtCore import QSomething, QWhatever, QElse`, this will make the migration script do the last step properly(including required adjustments where modules changed), so no try-except imports are needed.

Comment: you are right I used * to keep it simple, but I will change that, thanks for your feedback

Comment: this topic is the perfect place to tell people to not use *-imports, because here it actually does make a difference

Comment: @Hugo : Very detailed answer indeed, it helped a lot to get started. I will add the [qgis2compat](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgis2compat/) plugin to the numerous usefull resources already cited.

Comment: That's great idea. You can edit the answer as you want. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 2):

Try something like that:

```
try:
    # action for QGIS 3/PyQt5
except:
    # action for QGIS 2/PyQt4
```

Comment: This might work for some isolated things but will often not work as a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

I have just finished porting a QGIS Python plugin so that it now supports both 2.x and 3.x QGIS versions. Here is my experience:

Mostly I tried to rely on QGIS version. But even the class holding the version was a bit renamed. So I first did

```
try:
    from qgis.utils import Qgis  # for QGIS 3
except ImportError:
    from qgis.utils import QGis as Qgis  #  for QGIS 2
```

and then make checks

```
if Qgis.QGIS_VERSION >= '3.0':
    # something for QGIS 3
else:
    # something for QGIS 2
```

After deploying a final version I noticed that a file `resources.py` which is created automatically by `pyrcc5` also needs to be ported. Otherwise plugin will keep breaking down in 2.x. So I changed its line

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
```

to

```
try:
    from PyQt5 import QtCore
except:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore
```

It looked like it worked. I made an official release and thought that is it. Only then I discovered this sequence:

**Install my plugin in QGIS 2.18, close QGIS, open QGIS agan and then open Python Console inside QGIS -> The entire QGIS will instantly crash!**

After some testing I found out the reason was this small change in `resources.py` written above. I am no expert in QGIS Python libraries but my explanation is the following:

When I open QGIS my plugin gets initialized. Attempt of doing `from PyQt5 import QtCore` causes some changes in the QGIS "workflow" before wrong PyQt version raises an exception (it was a `RuntimeError`). When I start Python Console those changes cause QGIS to crash.

At the end I decided for a different solution. Because QGIS 2 uses Python 2.7 and QGIS 3 uses Python 3 I simply **always make checks for Python version**.

```
from sys import version_info

if version_info[0] >= 3:
    # something for QGIS 3
else:
    # something for QGIS 2
```

This avoids all potentially harmful import attempts. My plugin now works on both QGIS versions without any problems.