# Unit testing for QGIS 3 plugins

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, unit-testing

There is a nice resource on [unit testing for QGIS](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/developers_guide/unittesting.html). There is also a post on this, [Writing automated tests for QGIS plugins](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71206/writing-automated-tests-for-qgis-plugins), which requires the use of docker and relies on QGIS 2 plugin - [QGIS Tester](https://github.com/planetfederal/qgis-tester-plugin).

The progress on QGIS 3 is related to two plugins: 1) [Tester](https://github.com/qcooperative/qgis-tester-plugin) and 2) [QGIS Core Tests](https://github.com/qcooperative/qgis-core-tests).

How this all ties up with the final screen of QGIS Plugin Builder once we activate the `Unit Tests` checkbox? Where to start when we want to unit test the developed plugins?

[image]

Comment: Is there a directory named `test` in your newly created plugin directory ?

Comment: Yes, there is such a folder. We have also investigated two plugins: 1) QField Sync & 2) QGIS Core Tests. It appears that the QField Sync plugin did unit testing, and we are trying to understand the logic.

Comment: if you have a `test` directory, so you can look inside the `Makefile` for `make test` or just do Python unittest.

Comment: The files present under the `test` directory are 1) `__init__.py`, 2) `qgis_interface.py`,  3) `tenbytenraster.asc`, 4) `tenbytenraster.asc.aux.xml`, 5) `tenbytenraster.keywords`, 6) `tenbytenraster.lic`, 7) `tenbytenraster.prj`, 8) `tenbytenraster.qml`, 9) `test_init.py`, 10) `test_qgis_environment.py`, 11) `test_resources.py`,  12) `test_save_attributes_dialog.py`, 13) `test_translations.py` and 14)  `utilities.py`. These were created by default. When I look at the `tests` folder of the QField Sync plugin, it looks much tidy with only 6 Python files and a `data` folder.

Comment: So like I said, if you are under Linux distrib, in the plugin directory, in a terminal, you can run a `make test`, or just look in the Makefile under the `test` lines. See : https://g-sherman.github.io/Qgis-Plugin-Builder/#using-the-makefile . This will run typically Python unittest for all files begin with `test_`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org), you could try using [pytest-qgis](https://github.com/GispoCoding/pytest-qgis) plugin to write unit tests for QGIS. You don't need any of the boilerplate of starting the QGIS since it does it automatically.

Here is a sample test that checks that a layer has been added to the project:

```python
def test_plugin(qgis_countries_layer):
    project = QgsProject.instance()
    project.addMapLayer(qgis_countries_layer)
    assert project.count() == 1
    assert project.mapLayersByName(qgis_countries_layer.name()) == [qgis_countries_layer]
```

Since pytest is not part of the Python standard library, it is suggested that you create a virtual environment for running the tests:

1. `python -m venv --system-site-packages .venv`
2. `source .venv/bin/activate` or `.venv\Scripts\activate.bat` on Windows
3. `pip install pytest-qgis`
4. Finally run `pytest` to run the test(s)

Disclaimer: I am one of the authors of pytest-qgis.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution Joonala. Will this work for plugins that have GUI elements?

Comment: pytest-qgis works well with pytest-qt plugin, which is meant for interacting with Qt GUI elements. It can be used to handle automatic closing of dialogs, pressing buttons, waiting for qt signals and much more.