# Testing plugin out of QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, testing

There is a testing folder in the plugin's directory. Is there a way to launch tests outside the QGIS (without launching QGIS at all)?

Comment: Read https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/382998/unit-testing-for-qgis-3-plugins (edited the URL...)

Comment: I mean there are tests, but they're run only in QGIS. If to run them as scripts, they do not work

Comment: They do run as a script. I create a plugin from Plugin builder. Then I run `make test` from command line and it works. Not sure how you do. Edit your answer to tell us how you do as I'm not able to reproduce your issue.

Comment: PS: I use Linux